# Create custom bone shapes from vertex groups

Tags: mesh, objects, armature, bones

I have an armature parented to a mesh. The mesh is constructed from a set of cuboids which I created around each bone, where each bone controls only the vertex group around it, and these cuboids differ in length depending on the bone length. I wonder how I can create custom shapes for each of these bones to be exactly like the vertex group created for this bone?

As shown in the snap below, the armature is parented to a mesh where each bone has a vertex group assigned to it:

[image]

How I can create cutomeshapes for each bone to fit on the vertexgroup?